# Visual Studio 19 C++ namespace problems (has no member error)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, namespaces

I was working with VS19 (on Win 10) on my C++ project while suddenly every namespace reference got underlined with `Namespace X has no member Y` message. The behavior is very inconsistent:

- std references inside of my namespace have my namespace prepended in front of them so for example std::vector is actually being looked for in `MyNamespace::std::vector` (which i can mitigate using extra :: in front but does not solve incorrect references elsewhere + its clearly unnecessary in normal case)
- References to my namespace outside of my namespace are not finding the referenced classes but if I add the namespace name in front of it one more time it finds it (eg. `MyNamespace::Mynamespace::MyClass`)
- Some referenced classes from the namespace are even seen as classes and I can click and go into the class but its underlined with error anyway
- I get bunch of error-type problems in multiple types of situations, referencing instantiated classes from my custom namespace (but strangely not every time)

**I tried to** (according to various advises here at Stack and on the internet):

1. Undo the code changes which seemed to trigger it.
2. Restart VS.
3. Clean and rebuild solution.
4. Delete ipch folder as well as .suo.

The strangest thing is that it just happened but then again not the first time VS just went ham without any good reason.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]  ie create a new project with the smallest amount of code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could it be a closing `}` for `MyNamespace` missing in some header file or similar?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I went and manually checked the files and it was. I didn't add one of the files in git and i must've accidentally deleted it there. It was not even showing as an error in the file in that place so when I was looking for it I didn't see it. (accidently sent unfinished comment) Thank you very much

Comment: Oh, nice that it worked out!